# Assign value to missing data that isn't already in the array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, missing-data

I have a simple array, `a`, containing nine values between `1` and `10`. A missing data point in this array is given the value `0`.

I need to replace this value in the array with a value `0<x>10`, but crucially it cannot be a value that is already present in the input array.

```
import numpy as np
def Data(a):
    b = np.arange(1,10)
    a[a==0] = b[b != a]
    return a
```

I have tried this, but it seems to compare `a[0]` with `b[0]`, then `a[1]` and `b[1]`.

What I need it to do is compare `b[0]` with all values in the array `a`.
If the value of `b[0]` isn't found anywhere in a, then I need it to replace the value `0` (the missing data point in array `a`) with exactly `b[0]`.

Any smart and simple way to do this?

Comment: Replace all zeros with the same value, or different values? What if there aren't any (or enough) replacements?

Comment: In this i am assuming that only one value will be 0, and that there always will be only one number missing.

Comment: That seems like a relatively fragile assumption. But in that case I would suggest two steps: 1. Find the missing value. 2. Replace the zero with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for `numpy.in1d`, something like:

```
a[a == 0] = b[~np.in1d(b, a)]
```

For boolean arrays, `~` acts as a `not`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would ensure you have unique elements in `a`, and also replace the `0` values with a unique value in `range(1,11)`.

```
>>> a = [1,2,10,0,4,0,0,3,7]
>>> unique = set()
>>> a = [x if x not in unique and not unique.add(x) else 0 for x in a]
>>> new = list(set(range(1,11)) - unique)
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> shuffle(new)  # this step may be unnecessary...
>>> [new.pop() if x is 0 else x for x in a]
[1, 2, 10, 9, 4, 8, 6, 3, 7]
```